Does the system of ODE's for brushed DC motors also apply to BLDC motors?
The equations of motion for brushed DC motors are generally given as:
\$L \dot{I} + RI + k\omega = V_{in}\$
\$J\dot\omega\ = kI - b\omega\$
Where \$k\$ is the torque and velocity constant (assuming that SI units are being used), \$\omega\$ is the motor's angular frequency \$R\$ and \$L\$ are the armature resistance and inductance, respectively, \$J\$ is the rotor's mass moment of inertia, \$b\$ is the motor damping and \$I\$ is the motor current.
Can these same equations be used as the equations of motion of a brushless (wye winding) DC motor, with the line to line resistance and inductance replacing the armature resistance and inductance?  Will I obtain the correct speed/torque curve?
